# The sum of first n terms of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$1+(1+x)y+(1+x+x^2)y^2+ (1+x+x^2+x^3)y^3...... is$$

The $T_n$ term will be 
$$T_n=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} y^{n-1}$$
Then $$\sum T_n$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-x}\left[\sum y^{n-1}-\sum x^ny^{n-1}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-x}[\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}-.........]$$ I have put ‘....’ because I don’t know how to solve for $\sum x^ny^{n-1}$

Please help me with that .

Comment: $$\sum x^ny^{n-1}=\frac1y\sum (xy)^n=\dots$$

Comment: Since the summation appears to start at $n=1$, to turn it into a geometric sum, you should pull out the $x$ instead: $$\sum x^ny^{n-1} = x\sum (xy)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Also, $$\sum y^{n-1} = \dfrac{1-y^n}{1-y}$$ does not make sense as you have $n$ both inside and outside of the summation (on the LHS and the RHS). Instead, it would make more sense to write: $$\sum y^{n-1} = \dfrac{1}{1-y}$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I am not so sure about that. I didn’t understand why you did that thing with y, but what I did matches with the answer.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe could write it as $\sum y^{r-1}$ to not have n on both sides

Comment: @InterstellarProbe also regarding the $\sum (xy)^n$, pulling out y is more useful as it gives the right answer easily. Pulling out x will slightly extend the process